# c# using openssl.exe into a webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl

How can i use the command openssl.exe with cmd and those parameters:

> openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der

I write this C# code :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/c" + directoryWebPath + openssl.exe x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

But it is not working! When I execute manually it works but when I execute it from application web service C# it's not working! Why? :(

PS: How can i execute this exe from a remotewebservice ? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message that you get back?

Comment: More than error, simply does not run I can not create the file. Cer or. Der via the web application but instead manually works. The paths webapplication are perfectly correct. There is a way to convert the string of the certificate in pem to cer directly in memory? thanks

Comment: You could check out a library like [bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/).  This can generate certs in memory.